# Is it possible to place a circle that I have created in a Tkitnter window that already has few labels and entry boxes placed using the place method?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a need whereby I have already designed a GUI windows with few textboxes and labels for user input. I did this using the .place(x=..., y=...) method.

Now, I want to place a circle at a specific position using the same place(x=..., y=...) method in the same window with the already contained labels and textboxes. For this I tried calling the .create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2) method and placed it. However I doesn't seem to be working due to the already available textboxes and labels. Is it possible to be done, what I want?

Below is a **snippet** of my code-

```
from Tkinter import *

l0 = Label(root, image=photo)
l1 = Label(root, text="Server IP", fg="blue")
l2 = Label(root, text="Username", fg="blue")
l3 = Label(root, text="Port", fg="blue")
l4 = Label(root, text="Network Status", fg="black", font=("Arial", 14))
e1 = Entry(root, width=20)
e2 = Entry(root, width=20)
e3 = Entry(root, width=20)
loginbtn = Button(root,  bg="green", fg="white", text="Login", command=logindetails)
clearbtn = Button(root, bg="red", fg="white", text="Clear", command=cleartext)

#draw the circles to show network status
w = Canvas(root, width=630, height=350)
w.create_oval(500,40,560,100, fill="blue")


l0.place(x=10, y=10)
l1.place(x=10, y=210)
e1.place(x=90, y =210)
l2.place(x=10, y=240)
e2.place(x=90, y=240)
l3.place(x=10, y=270)
e3.place(x=90, y=270)

l4.place(x=490, y=20)
w.place(x=500, y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this program, I get an output but not with the circle created. Where have I missed in here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You got most of the way to an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but your code does not run as posted.

You missed two things: 1) you only need a convas slightly bigger than the circle you want to display -- see revised Canvas statement; 2) you need your container big enough to show everything, and toplevels do not expand by themselves -- see root.geometry.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x400')
l1 = Label(root, text="Server IP", fg="blue")
l2 = Label(root, text="Username", fg="blue")
l3 = Label(root, text="Port", fg="blue")
l4 = Label(root, text="Network Status", fg="black", font=("Arial", 14))
e1 = Entry(root, width=20)
e2 = Entry(root, width=20)
e3 = Entry(root, width=20)

#draw the circles to show network status
w = Canvas(root, width=64, height=64)
w.create_oval(2,2,62,62, fill="blue")

l1.place(x=10, y=210)
e1.place(x=90, y =210)
l2.place(x=10, y=240)
e2.place(x=90, y=240)
l3.place(x=10, y=270)
e3.place(x=90, y=270)

l4.place(x=490, y=20)
w.place(x=500, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```

This slightly revised code works more or less as I believe you want.  Note that some margin is needed around circle to avoid 'flattening'.

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked. Is it also possible that a canvas be laid out on top of an image label?